# Video metadata edit with Ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata

I want to change the video metadata.

Orginal video info(ffmpeg -i video.mp4)

```
     Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isomavc1mp42
    creation_time   : 2007-11-22 09:11:58
  Duration: 00:00:52.70, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 235 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 107 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2007-11-22 09:11:58
      handler_name    : (C) 2007 Google Inc. v06.24.2007.
    Stream #0:1(und): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 140x96 [SAR 1:1 DAR 35:24], 125 kb/s, 10 fps, 10 tbr, 10k tbn, 20k tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2007-11-22 09:11:58
      handler_name    : (C) 2007 Google Inc. v06.24.2007.
```

My ffmpeg shell code:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -metadata handler_name="Ahmetka" -i logo.png -filter_complex "overlay=(main_w-overlay_w):(main_h-overlay_h)" output.flv
```

Output video info(ffmpeg -i output.flv)

```
    Input #0, flv, from 'output.flv':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isomavc1mp42
    creation_time   : 2007-11-22 09:11:58
    encoder         : Lavf54.11.100
  Duration: 00:00:53.60, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 212 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: flv1, yuv420p, 140x96, 200 kb/s, 10 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s
```

How can I do?

Comment: Looks OK. Maybe try to move the `-metadata` option to the end of the command, after any `-i`.